# MATLAB vectorized code return wrong result

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm taking a MATLAB course and have written the following code. One is a FOR LOOP and the other is a vectorization. The FOR LOOP returns the correct result but the vectorization does not. Can anyone tell me  what I have coded incorrectly?

Should be for the following equation.

> 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - ... - 1/1003    (sum is 0.7849 - converges
>   slowly to pi/4)

USE FOR LOOP

```
clc
clear
tic
sign = -1;
y=0;
for x=1:2:1003
    sign=-sign;
    y=y+sign/x;
end

disp(['For Loop calculated ' num2str(y), ' and ran for ' num2str(toc)])
```

USE VECTORIZATION

```
clear
tic
n=1:2:1003;
x=sum(1./n -1./(n+2));
disp(['Vectorization calculated ' num2str(x), ' and ran for ' num2str(toc)])
```

Answer (score 2):

In the vectorized code, replace the `x` line by this:

```
x = sum(1./n .* (-1).^(0:numel(n)-1))
```

The term after `1./n` takes care of the alternating sign.

As it stands now, your code `sum(1./n -1./(n+2))`  is giving you 1+1/3+1/5+...+1/1003 - (1/3+1/5+...+1/1005), that is (after cancellation of terms), 1-1/1005.

Answer (score 2):

You could either change the formula you use in your summation ([as suggested by Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20735653/52738)), or you could keep your formula and just change the step size you take in your `n` vector to this:

```
n = 1:4:1003;
```